# What is the quick way to create a 2d numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I am creating this array:

```
>>> np.array([[0,1,2,3,4,5],[10,11,12,13,14,15],[20,21,22,23,24,25],[30,31,32,33,34,35],[40,41,42,43,44,45],[50,51,52,53,54,55]])

array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
       [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45],
       [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55]])
```

I am typing all the elements out

Answer (score 4):

Hm, you could always use a list-comprehension if you already don't mind using an auxiliary list:

```
>>> np.array([list(range(i, i + 6)) for i in range(0, 55, 10)])
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
       [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45],
       [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55]])
```

And here's a `numpy` way using broadcasting:

```
>>> np.arange(0, 51, 10).reshape(-1, 1) + np.arange(6)
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
       [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45],
       [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55]])
```

This approach, especially for larger examples, will be faster and require much less auxiliary storage.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an [`mgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html) class instance for this.

```
import numpy as np

y, x = np.mgrid[:60:10, :6]
a = y + x
print(a)
```

**output**

```
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5]
 [10 11 12 13 14 15]
 [20 21 22 23 24 25]
 [30 31 32 33 34 35]
 [40 41 42 43 44 45]
 [50 51 52 53 54 55]]
```

---

A minor variation is to use the Numpy `sum` function to perform the addition of the two arrays:

```
a = np.sum(np.mgrid[:60:10, :6], axis=0)
```

However, as user2357112 mentions in the comments, it's more efficient to just do the addition with the `+`operator rather than calling a function.

He also mentions that we can use `ogrid` to create column and row arrays, which consumes less RAM for `y` and `x`. And it's faster too.

```
import numpy as np
y, x = np.ogrid[:60:10, :6]
a = y + x
print(y, x, a, sep='\n\n')
```

**output**

```
 [10]
 [20]
 [30]
 [40]
 [50]]

[[0 1 2 3 4 5]]

[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5]
 [10 11 12 13 14 15]
 [20 21 22 23 24 25]
 [30 31 32 33 34 35]
 [40 41 42 43 44 45]
 [50 51 52 53 54 55]]
```

Comment: nice! This is handy.

Comment: No point using `sum` just to add two arrays. (Also, you could use `ogrid` instead of `mgrid` to create smaller temporaries. I don't know whether this would be any faster.)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks! `mgrid` is very handy. But it is slightly weird in that it's a class instance that looks like an array, but it creates the values when you index it.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks, I'll add that info to my answer.